# how to check session variable existence in MVC before we do any activity on page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I have a scenario like :

search control where our data entry guys enter user id and search for their details and navigate through different pages related to that user.

So in my MVC application right now i am setting a session to maintain the user id in session variable. And on every method on page (like edit, update ..etc) I am checking if user session exist or not. Can i do it globally so i don't need to check every time? Like in global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
}
```

or write a custom method to check the session.

Please can somebody help me the way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In MVC application you can make own attribute that inherits from [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) ,
and then in that attribute you can check your session. And you can place it on needed controllers, or to GlobalFilters collection.

**UPDATE1**

Here is a sample of such logic

```
public class SessionAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return httpContext.Session["InsuredKey"] != null;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/some/error");
    }
}
```

And then you can place it under needed controllers like

```
[SessionAuthorize]
public class SomeController
{
}
```

Comment: Do you think [Authorize(Session["InsuredKey"] != null)]  will work on controller class?

Comment: No, it won't. You need to write custom implementation.

Comment: I think this works perfect in my scenario. I have one dumb question though. Do you think i can place this SessionAuthorizeAttribute class in my class library project which is part of the solution?

Comment: Sure, it can be placed anywhere, but this library should be referenced in MVC application.

Comment: One last question...where does it redirect the page if  sessionauthorize class returns false?

Comment: by default it uses LoginUrl from web.config, but you make specific page just for this case by overriding HandleUnauthorizedRequest method in that attribute. I've updated code with sample

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer actually does not redirect to the page specified at `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` time.

I had to modify few things to make it work

```
public class SessionAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return httpContext.Session["InsuredKey"] != null;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                              new RouteValueDictionary
                              {
                                   { "action", "YourAction" },
                                   { "controller", "YourController" }
                              });
    }
}
```

It might be helpful for future users.