# Check session before running controller issue in ASP.NET core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

So I want to check if a session exists before running any action in the controller. I found these solutions [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42819508/5612132),[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20787797/how-to-check-session-variable-existence-in-mvc-before-we-do-any-activity-on-page) and tried implementing them.
This is my `SessionAuthorize` class, everything seems fine here:

```
public class SessionAuthorize : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly SessionManager _sessionManager;
    public SessionAuthorize(SessionManager sessionManager)
    {
        _sessionManager = sessionManager;
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        if (!_sessionManager.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary {
                            { "Controller", "Home" },
                            { "Action", "Login" }
                            });
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the issue am having is when I try to call it in the controller. So I am supposed to call by adding the `[SessionAuthorize]` attribute like this:

```
[SessionAuthorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    //code
}
```

But it gives me the error that I am not calling it properly. I believe it has to do with the dependency injection I used in `SessionAuthorize` to access the session. But I am not sure how to call it now.

The error message is:

> 'There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
> parameter 'sessionManager' of
> 'SessionAuthorize.SessionAuthorize(SessionManager)'

So I would like to know how am I supposed to use it in my controller

Comment: What's that SessionManager class? Is it a class you wrote or from a library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid the Service Locator pattern you can use DI by constructor injection with a `TypeFilter`.

In your controller try using

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(SessionAuthorize)]
```

And your `ActionFilterAttribute` does not need to access a service provider instance anymore.